# get ApplicationContext on react-native

Tags: swift, reactjs, react-native, watchkit, react-native-ios

I have a watchKit app connected with a react-native iOS app with [react-native-watch-connectivity](https://github.com/mtford90/react-native-watch-connectivity).

I want to use the applicationContext to communicate between the devices.

From react-native, I use `watch.updateApplicationContext({ dataFromRN: "data" })` to define it and I can get it in iWatch side.

**But when I use `updateApplicationContext(["data":"data"])` in iWatch side, an updated context event is catch by react-native but the data is not updated.**

```
// iWatch
try session?.updateApplicationContext(["dataFromWatch":"data"])
print(session?.applicationContext ?? "")
```

> ["dataFromWatch": "data"]

but in react-native, I have the following output for this event:

```
// react-native iOS
receiveApplicationContext(err, applicationContext) {
  console.log("receiveApplicationContext()", applicationContext)
```

> receiveApplicationContext() {dataFromRN: "data"}

dataFromRN is a previous applicationContext defined from react-native side.

Event if react-native catch an event, the applicationContext is not updated.

(react-native-watch-connectivity has react version defined to **15.4.2** but I'm using react **16.2.0**. Is something can be breaking changed between this versions ?)

I guess I have to update something in react-native-watch-connectivity, but I would like to know where.

If you have any element to fix this issue...

Thx

iOS side (with react-native)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableHighlight
} from "react-native";
import * as watch from "react-native-watch-connectivity";

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { match: [] };
    this.receiveUserInfo = this.receiveUserInfo.bind(this);
    this.subscribeToApplicationContext = this.subscribeToApplicationContext.bind(this);
    this.subscribeToWatchEvents = this.subscribeToWatchEvents.bind(this);
  }

  receiveUserInfo(err, userInfo) {
    if (!err) {
      if (userInfo.currentMatch !== undefined) {
        console.log("receiveUserInfo()", userInfo);
      }
    }
  }

  receiveApplicationContext(err, applicationContext) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("receiveApplicationContext()", applicationContext);
        watch.getApplicationContext().then(context => {
        console.log("getApplicationContext()", context);
      });
    }
  }

  subscribeToWatchEvents() {
    this.subscriptions = [
      watch.subscribeToUserInfo(this.receiveUserInfo),
      watch.subscribeToApplicationContext(this.receiveApplicationContext)
    ];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscribeToWatchEvents();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}
```

iWatch side (swift)

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class MainController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

  var session: WCSession?

  override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
      self.session = WCSession.default
      self.session?.delegate = self
      self.session?.activate()
    }
  }

  func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    print("activationDidCompleteWith", activationState)
  }

  func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
    print("didReceiveApplicationContext", applicationContext)
  }

  func sendUserInfo() {
    session?.transferUserInfo(["data":"data"])
    do {
      try session?.updateApplicationContext(["data":"data"])
    } catch {
      print("updateApplicationContext error")
    }
    print(session?.applicationContext ?? "")
  }

  @IBAction func point() {
    sendUserInfo()
  }

}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear

Comment: The applicationContext work when it send from iOS to iWatch, but not from iWatch to iOS (an event is triggered, but the applicationContext data is not updated)

Comment: Share your iOS `UIViewController` or equivalent code. Just to see the iPhone counterpart side.

Comment: I'm using react-native and I use https://github.com/mtford90/react-native-watch-connectivity to catch the data from iWatch

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any issue in your `MainController` `InterfaceController` but if you send the same message via `updateApplicationContext:`, it's ignored on the other counterpart app by default.

Basically, do not to send the same `applicationContext`.

Check this, for test purpose, we just add a random number to the `applicationContext` payload so it is different for successive calls.

```
func sendUserInfo() {
    do {
        try session?.updateApplicationContext(["from" : "watch \(arc4random()"])
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: When the same applicationContext is sent the event is not triggered at all. Actually I send an array who is updated at each call.

Comment: @Paul I created a sample project based on the code you shared and things are going fine for me. Help me recreate your problem. Share a sample project having this issue using `react-native-watch-connectivity `

Comment: With which version of react / react-native ?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the library react-native-watch-connectivity (maybe a problem with the react version I'm using), I would like to update it but I don't where the problem can be.

Comment: @Paul You should update your question with your react implementation because the issue seems to lie on that side. Also check the basic documentation on [Application Context of react-native-watch-connectivity](https://github.com/mtford90/react-native-watch-connectivity#application-context)

Comment: ok it was a bug in `react-native-watch-connectivity`. I created a pull request to fix the problem.

Comment: @Paul damn dem bugs -_- but glad you got it confirmed.

Comment: @Paul A liitle help required. I am trying to send data using updateApplicationContext from react (phone) side to watch side. No exception is raised but data is not received on the watch side. Normal send message is working fine. Can you give any pointers. Using RN version 0.65.1